# Is there a blog module in Tridion?

Tags: publishing

We're developing some regional sites for a big customer. Most of the product managers want to add a Blog in their websites.
We're now actually working with articles for the blog posts but I'm wondering if there's a blog module as the same as the Blog webpart in MS Sharepoint.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

SDL Tridion is a best of breed product which means that for the Content Delivery tier there aren't really ready made parts available. Because of the Template Model and the way you implement a website in SDL Tridion you actually have a lot of options available here. For instance you could use the [BlogEngine.NET Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/blog-engine) if you are building a .NET website.

Another option there is available is (as you describe) using articles for blog posts, you can compliment this with the SDL Tridion Community Builder (a.k.a. User Generated Content or UGC) to add comments and ratings to your blog posts. This is exactly what is currently done on [the SDL Blog](http://blog.sdl.com). But I have to add such a structure would only work when your bloggers have access to the CMS, for a open community type of blog, you are probably looking more for a third party (open source) blogging engine.

Comment: This question ("can we do a blog with Tridion") has come up in some of my recent client discussions. I suggested the same as you, @Bart, but point out some hybrid integration options [in this post](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/11/making-blog-with-sdl-tridion.html). With the right code to add comments, sharing, and other "blog features," the rest is *just* templating.

Answer (score 5):

Tridion starts out with some pretty good out-of-the-box functionality that you can use to build a blog, but you'll have to do some work yourself.

1. Tridion has one of the best Rich Text editors you'll find anywhere. So allowing your authors to create blog posts is simply a matter of creating a schema with a big RTF field, and maybe a couple of metadata fields (keywords and such).
2. Tridion's standard content delivery libraries make it easy to create a page that lists your blog posts in reverse-chronological order. There should be a dynamic component template, so publishing a blog becomes just publishing the component. If you have the right metadata, you can also list the posts in other ways - for example, filtered by keywords.
3. If you need comments, you can use either Tridion's own User Generated Content module, or an external commenting system.

So with these features (and more) as standard, Tridion doesn't really need a separate "blogging module". All that you need is in the core product.

Comment: Why are we answering posts of 6 months ago ?

Comment: Any reason why not? As it happens, it was brought to my attention because someone added a spam answer - which was probably so quickly closed that most people didn't see it.

Comment: Revisiting answers also help as the product evolves. For example, things like UGC and Translation Manager were added to the core installation. Now with the Tridion Reference Implementation (TRI), many questions asking for examples could use an update as well. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to refer [THIS](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/wordpress.aspx) great post from Albert which suggest there is an extension for the same supported in earlier version of Tridion. You may want to explore the approach mentioned and try to build something which supports latest version of SDL Tridion and share it with the community.